# pci-express ssd running an OS

Tags: ssd, pci-express

Simple question really, is it possible to install an OS such as Windows or Ubuntu on a PCI-Express SSD (solid state drive)?

And if so is it as straight forward as selecting that drive on install?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the drive, but in my experience, it is not as easy as a standard hard drive.

There are many different sorts of PCI Express SSDs, however most of them I have come across basically act as raid/sata extenders. They usually come with a driver disk and all you have to do is during Windows setup, click on the load driver button and then it will work as a normal hard drive.

[image]

(Bottom left hand corner).

However, you may get lucky and it may use a chip that Windows knows and it could just work.

Comment: FYI The drive itself doesn't determine if it is used as a RAID, IDE or AHCI device, the controller does.